# Plotting data blocks of varying length using PGFPlots and gnuplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot

Consider this MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
"Amplitude","notes: data set 1",
X,Y,
1,1,
2,2,
3,3,
4,4,

"CH1","notes: data set 1",
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        \addplot gnuplot [raw gnuplot, mark=none, black]{
            set datafile separator comma;
            plot "data.csv" using 1:2 every ::3::6 with lines;
        };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

where I've used `gnuplot` to plot data from a `.csv` file. Regarding the format of my `.csv` file, I know the data always starts on line 3, however I don't know how long the data will be. When dealing with 1 set of data like in this example, it's not too difficult to just count that there are 4 lines and put this in manually - `every ::3::6 with lines` (i.e. from line 3 to line 6).

My issue is that my real `.csv` file is a lot more complicated - it includes multiple data blocks and they all have different lengths (which I don't know exactly how long without manually checking, on the order of 2000+ points). This extension of my MWE illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
"Amplitude","notes: data set 1",
X,Y,
1,1,
2,2,
3,3,
4,4,

"Amplitude","notes: data set 2",
X,Y,
1,7,
2,6,
3,5,
4,4,
5,3,
6,2,
7,1,

"CH1","notes: data set 1",
"CH1","notes: data set 2",
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis} [width=0.5\textwidth,height=7cm,
        ]
        \addplot gnuplot [raw gnuplot, mark=none, black]{
            set datafile separator comma;
            plot "data.csv" using 1:2 every ::3::6 with lines;
        };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to automate how this `.csv` file is processed? Ideally, I'd like to make this so TeX can work out how many data blocks are stored in the `.csv` and then I can select which data blocks to plot (some on individual plots, some together).

FYI, the purpose of this to enable automatic generation of reports. I select the data file, and choose the blocks I want to plot and hit run and the document automatically generates.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, as I don't know how to use `pgfplots` and `gnuplot`.  However, this answer shows how to use `readarray` (and its underlying `listofitems`) to extract a piece of an input file.

You just now have to figure out how to pass that extracted piece to `gnuplot`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,filecontents,readarray}

\begin{filecontents*}{mydata.csv}
"Amplitude","notes: data set 1",
X,Y,
1,1,
2,2,
3,3,
4,4,

"Amplitude","notes: data set 2",
X,Y,
1,7,
2,6,
3,5,
4,4,
5,3,
6,2,
7,1,

"CH1","notes: data set 1",
"CH1","notes: data set 2",
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\readarraysepchar{\\}
\readdef{mydata.csv}\mydata
\ignoreemptyitems
\setsepchar{%
    "Amplitude","notes: data set 2",% START OF DATA SET
  /%
    "CH1","notes: data set 1",% END OF DATA SET
  /%
    \\% SAME UNIQUE TOKEN STRING SET IN \readarraysepchar
}
\readlist\myarray{\mydata}
\noindent\foreachitem\x\in\myarray[2,1]{\xcnt: \x\\}
\end{document}
```

[image]